# How to strip whitespace and not punctuation from the end of a list element

Tags: python

I want to strip the whitespace from the end of list elements, but not any punctuation that might be present. The code being used to print the elements is:

```
for string in list:
    if [condition]:
        print(string.strip())
```

But this removes punctuation from the end of the list, which is not what I want. However, if I leave out the .strip() it puts an empty line between each output, which I also don't want. In my searches, I've only found ways to remove both whitespace and punctuation, not just whitespace.

Comment: Why do you think it strips punctuation?

Comment: `strip()` with no arguments only removes whitespaces. It does not remove punctuation. Therefore your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: are you sure? Something like `"   %abcd*   \t     \n     \n".strip()` outputs `'%abcd*'`

Comment: "this removes punctuation from the end of the list" You are **not** applying `strip()` to `list`. Rather you are applying it to each **element** of list. It sounds like you are losing information when creating `list` in the first place. Please show the code that does this along with example input and output. Also be sure to explain how the output differs from what you want.

Answer (score -1):

maybe using `re`?

```
import re

for string in list:
    if [condition]:
        print(re.sub(r"\s+", "", string))
```

Comment: If someone is going to downvote me, better comment here a better solution for this question or explain to me what I missed...